# Flickering while rendering a CALayer -> MTLTexture, via CARenderer on background thread

Tags: swift, calayer, metal

I'm trying to render a layer tree, via CARenderer, ideally on a background thread, and running into weird rendering/flicker issues

---

##### Progress as of 25th Oct

Not knowing exactly WHERE the issue was cropping up (my CARenderer -> MTLTexture creator? the view? the conversion to a CMSampleBuffer for writing vidoe?), I wrote a simple shader to count the number of pink pixels per frame, that executed almost directly after the CARenderer.render() was called.

I then used to this to trigger writes of "bad/problematic" frames to files. This is the kind of thing I saw:

[image: Weird half baked render]

Note: the rendering system (see the code) is now using a MTLHeap for its textures, so it should not be possible that some other thread/task in the app is reusing and overwriting that texture in parallel.

The key parts to the "render a CALayer to a MTLTexture" code is this:

```
    if let renderCommandBuffer: MTLCommandBuffer = queue.makeCommandBuffer() {
        let renderCommandEncoder: MTLRenderCommandEncoder = renderCommandBuffer.makeRenderCommandEncoder(descriptor: currentDescriptor)!
        renderCommandEncoder.label = "Clear Target"
        renderCommandEncoder.endEncoding()
        renderCommandBuffer.commit()
        renderCommandBuffer.waitUntilScheduled()

        rendererToUse.beginFrame(atTime: CACurrentMediaTime(), timeStamp: nil)
        rendererToUse.addUpdate(rendererToUse.bounds)
        rendererToUse.render()
        rendererToUse.endFrame()
```

Note the lack of a "rendererToUse.waitForMeToBeDoneThanksVeryMuch()"
And "rendererToUse" is a CARenderer.

So it seemed to me that the "rendererToUse" (a CARenderer instance) was possibly still executing at the time I used the MTLTexture (either to count it's pink pixels, show in a view / save to a movie).

So I changed the MTLHeap to use a MTLHazardTrackingMode of .tracked.
This *seems* so far, to have solved the problem.
It seems heavy handed tho - since the synchronization is apparently at the HEAP level (I presume that to mean all access to anything vended by the heap is serialized). I don't know yet if that means that I can't be writing to two/three textures from the heap at the same time, or if it means access to each invidually vended texture from the heap is independently serialized.

So my question I think now morphs to this:

Assuming I'm even on the right track here: How do you force a CARenderer to do an equivalent of .waitUntilComplete()? Given that you can't get hold of the command buffer, nor any encoders that it might be creating/using. The textures from the MTLHeap are .private, so you can't perform any blit synchronization on them that I can see (all attempts at that fail for me, with various storageMode validation assertions), and a MTLHeap can't vend .shared or .managed textures that I know of (tried that, failed with validation assertions)

I'm still not 100% certain I'm right. But so far, the "very large hammer" approach of hazard=.tracked for the textures coming from the heap seems to do it.

Have I missed something perhaps more obvious?
Given my Metal experience is low - that's quite possible.  Any hints / questions or ideas appreciated.

---- Original Post

I'm seeing flicking when I run the render method on a non-main thread (see renderLayerToMTLTexture).  If I run on a main thread its better but there is still flicker, just much less.

[image]

For video, see: https://www.dropbox.com/s/7uhg7nyjde3h1rt/Purple%20flicker%20of%20doom.mov?dl=0

- note: the background is being cleared to pink to make it more obvious.

The code producing the texture:
https://gist.github.com/scornflake/0f42841e377e99440910c43f7424f0a5

The context is that events are being generated (throttled to 60fps), requesting render to texture for a given layer (that layer being a composition of other layers).  These textures are either painted to the screen (in preview mode) or sent to a video writer (to create a movie).

Flicking occurs both on screen & in the movie. Thus I am so far presuming that the flickering is not a result of my texture preview MTKView, but rather a problem in my CALayerToMetalRenderer.

What I've tried so far:

- double/tripple buffering (helps a bit, but problem still there even with tripple buffers)
- doing a blit to synchronize on the texture resource (seems to have no effect at all)
- creating the texture with a storageMode of .private - since I never need the texture available to the CPU. In doing this I have to remove the synchronization blit, I'm guessing because the texture is now no longer CPU accessible thus sync is invalid.
- passing my own MTLCommandQueue queue to CARenderer (options, in constructor), to see if manually synchronizing on the texture resources works. No change.

I'm no metal expert, but it *feels* to me like the initial render command (to clear the texture) is working, but the CARenderer .render is sometimes not / or perhaps sometimes late? (yes, grasping at straws here a bit)

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you looked at a captured Metal frame(s) to verify it is being rendered in time? It also has nice graphs that show timing. Have you tried a lower frame rate, like perhaps 30?

Comment: @JeshuaLacock - no, I've not captured them. I tried, but xcode crashes after taking the capture so I can't look at it (on both intel and also my m1)

Comment: @JeshuaLacock - Actually. Yes. Managed to do that - except I'm not knowledgeable enough in metal to make much sense of it. The frames look OK. I've not captured a solid pink (my debug color) frame yet. I can see the stages doing what I think they are supposed to.

Comment: Happy to look if you post some screenshots.

Comment: OK - I've taken some pics + video. 

1. Me [Taking the sample](https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/apvy0xdh78pipfbs365y6/Taking-the-capture.mov?rlkey=necvfjvlxoj6txcomgvwr9a64&dl=0)

2. [Walking through] the sample(https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/w7dcck28izhl1caacj761/Stepping-through-one-of-the-traces.mov?rlkey=3jtmcim39533e68jkej25rhcd&dl=0)

3. [The trace itself](https://www.dropbox.com/s/eisuzmgm646t2vi/iShowU6%20GPUTrace.gputrace.zip?dl=0)

I can send screenshots if you like, but at least with video you can I hope see a ton more.

Comment: I should note that I have since modified the code that produces the textures to use a MTLHeap of textures.  There's no additional synchronization going on.  I did this to try to guarantee that no other code would be writing to the texture until that texture is released.

The new code for the texture generation is here:
https://gist.github.com/scornflake/e5b2d9342ad14822bfa020262d7081ee

Also, the wrapper for the heap is here: https://gist.github.com/scornflake/28a964e8cfb0ab5ddc58b7427160a5e7